# jquery selectors problem

Tags: jquery, xhtml, jquery-selectors

I have an issue using jquerys selectors when it comes to a page I am populating from a database.

The database populates a  which will display 4 `<li>` tags per row for x amount of rows.

I am trying to use addClass to give the first and last result on each row of the `<ul>` a different class.

I have tried :first and :last but these obviously only add the classes needed to the very first result and the very last result. I need the added to the first and last of each row of 4.

My current code is:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#display li.thumbs:first").addClass("start");
    $("ul#display li.thumbs:last").addClass("end");
  });
```

Example HTML

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/">image 12</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of how the HTML for at least two or three rows would look?

Comment: So the markup is: <ul id="display">
<li>something</li><li>something</li><li>something</li><li>something</li></ul> ..  or are there multiple sets of 4 rows. Your question is worded as though there might be more than 4 <li>'s on the page, but might not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673983/how-to-stripe-rows-for-a-multiple-row-record-using-jquery), which basically involves using `each()` along with an index number `i`.  Apply a modulus operator to see where each element falls in the set of four:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#display li.thumbs").each(function(i) { 
        if (i % 4 == 0) 
           $(this).addClass("start");
        if (i % 4 == 3) 
           $(this).addClass("end");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [nth-child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild) selector:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(4n-3)").addClass("start");
$("ul li:nth-child(4n)").addClass("end");
```

Check a [sample](http://jsbin.com/ereke) with your markup.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

This is some sample code from my [test page](http://www.arvag.net/test/jquery/) under "click to see some jquery selectors":

```
    // JS THAT DO THE JOB FOR JQUERY SELECTORS
    $('#jquerySelectorsUl li:nth-child(7)').addClass('alert');
    $('#jquerySelectorsUl li a[title=test]').addClass('alert');
    // JS THAT DO THE JOB FOR LI ADD/REMOVE
    var i = $('#addRemove li').size();
    $('#add').click(function() {
        i++;
        $('<li>' + i + '</li>').appendTo('#addRemove');
    });
    $('#remove').click(function() {
        $('#addRemove li:last').remove();
        if (i != 0){
            i--;
        };
    });
```

Maybe this will help you even though its not really straight answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#display li.thumbs:first-child").addClass("start");
    $("ul#display li.thumbs:last-child").addClass("end");
});
```

`first-child` and `last-child` retrieve the list items if they are the first/last children of their immediate parent. So if there is a list item without `class="thumbs"` between the `<ul>` and the first `<li class="thumbs">`, then there will not be a match to the first selector.

Comment: this unfortunatley does not work as it only selects the very first and very last <li> tags in the <ul>, not the first and last of each row.

Answer (score 0):

I like being able to change my mind about how many constitute a set in cases like this:

```
    var per_set = 4;
    $('ul li').each(function(index){
        if (index % per_set === 0) {
            $(this).addClass("start");
        } else if (index % per_set === (per_set-1)) {
            $(this).addClass("end");
        }
    });
```